# How to play twilio call recording in c# asp.net

Tags: c#, twilio

With twilio api, I am recording the call between two users using `<Dial>` verb. I am able to see the recorded call listing on logging into to twilio account. I now want to play the recorded call in asp.net page, is it possible ?

Also when I try to listen the call in twilio account listing, it keeps asking me username/password and doesn't let me listen the recording after providing my twilio account's username/password. What credentials is it expecting me to provide ?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio evangelist here.

Sure, playing recordings is totally possible.  Twilio makes recordings are available in [both wav and mp3 format](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#instance-get).  To get the MP3 format, just add *.mp3* to the URL:

```
/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACda6f1.../Recordings/RE557ce644e5ab84fa21cc21112e22c485.mp3
```

As far as I know, by default you should not need to provide credentials in order to get a recording.  If Twilio is asking for credentials it may be possible that your account has that feature enabled.  I would try sending your AccountSid and Authtoken credentials as a Basic authentication header when you make the request.

Once you get a recording, how you play it in the browser is going to depend on what browsers you need to support. Scott Hanselman wrote a great blog post on how to use the HTML 5 `<audio>` tag with a nice fallback to Flash player here:

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/FallbackHTML5AudioTagsForASimpleMP3PodcastAreHarderThanYoudThink.aspx

Hope that helps.

Comment: I thought the same. But not sure why one of our users found this issue this morning. Twilio recordings are prompting for password. While they should be public as per twilio documentation.